# is a dove a "she"? how to use "he" and "she" for animals?

Tags: word-usage

In the song "Blowing in the Wind" by Bob Dylan, there's a verse that reads:

> Yes, and how many seas must a white dove sail
>
> Before **she** sleeps in the sand?

My question is, why he used "she" for a dove? What about other animals and other non-humans? Is there a general rule?

Comment: See also [this question about ants](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53132/6700).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason he refers to the dove as "she" is actually very simple. It's because this is poetry. Lyrics don't always follow grammar rules and conventions.

In everyday English, the correct pronoun for an animal is "it", if the sex of the animal is unknown. If the sex is known, you would use the same pronoun as you would when referring to a human, "he" or "she", although you could still use "it".

Comment: Dylan may have gone for 'she' in this case because he's talking about the dove sailing on the sea like a ship, and ships are always referred to as 'she'.

Comment: @ssav oh, that's a really good point, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I'll disagree with ssav. When anthropomorphizing animals, gender is optional when referring to the species rather than individuals. A common standard is to use "he" for fierce or strong varieties, and "she" for the pretty and the weak. Rampant sexism, but there it is. Traditional folk music (Dylan's background when he wrote this) commonly referred to birds as she ("Oh, the cuckoo, she's a pretty bird, she sings as she flies"). Doves are small and pretty, so he used "she".

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I think you're on to something, but I'm not sure "pretty and weak" is the precise categorization. Typically male=>war/fighting and female=>peace/love and a dove is a traditional symbol of peace, like "hawks versus doves" in the political arena.

Comment: @ColleenV that's what what I was thinking also. I think these are all valid points, but lyric interpretation is very subjective, so the only way to know for sure would be to ask Bob Dylan himself.

Comment: Why Dylan chose it is certainly subjective unless we ask him, and I  think your answer covers the language part of the question very well. I think it's helpful to speculate a little in the comments though just to give some insight into how using he or she with an animal might be interpreted by folks fluent in English.

Comment: @ColleenV - Ahem. You did notice the sentence about rampant sexism? In English/Scottish folk songs, pretty and weak are restricted to "the weaker sex". And as another example, from "Captain Woodstock's Courtship", "The dove she is a gentle bird, And she flies without a gall" with no connection to peace. And the antiwar song "La Colombe" ("The Dove) by Jacques Brel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjYC8ZBdeGU shows the French gender for dove is feminine, as is the translation ("The dove has torn her wing").

Comment: Dove seems to have feminine gender in languages of both Latin and Germanic origin (cfr. German *Taube*). Incidentally, the same isn't true of all small birds (sparrow, nightingale, wren are all masculine in Italian).

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'm not saying you're wrong; I'm saying that my interpretation is Dove->Peace->Feminine. Doves aren't particularly weak or pretty to me. Peacocks are pretty, but they are masculine. I might call a vain man a peacock, but not a vain woman. I don't think it's particularly sexist, it's just a cultural association. [Kali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi#Kali) is neither pretty nor weak ;)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - An admission: yeah, I know that. And for languages such as French, the gender of an object is not a matter of choice, so the use of the feminine article for "colombe" is not up to the writer the same way "before she sleeps in the sand" was for Dylan.