# Pronoun for animals and trees

Tags: pronouns

Which pronoun should be used for animals and for trees?
Is there any change in pronoun according to the situation? If yes, then what is it?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52891/is-a-dove-a-she-how-to-use-he-and-she-for-animals/ and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53132/can-i-refer-to-an-ant-as-she

Answer (score 3):

"It" is the pronoun used (in general).

You may want to know more from this [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it), definition 1 copied below:

> "that one —used as subject or direct object or indirect object of a verb or object of a preposition usually in reference to a lifeless thing (took a quick look at the house and noticed it was very old), a **plant** (there is a rosebush near the fence and it is now blooming), a person or **animal** whose sex is unknown or disregarded (don't know who it is), a group of individuals or things, or an abstract entity (beauty is everywhere and it is a source of joy)"

Situation? You mean [this](http://www.englishcorner.vacau.com/grammar/prntbl.html)?

Comment: As an interesting, if rare, exception to "it" for plants, gendered pronouns are occasionally used either when the plant is a particular specimen of a species or when the plant's gender is known and significant.  For example, General Sherman is a particular sequoia tree in California and it would be normal to call it "him."  Similarly, a female tree might be called "her" if you were discussing its potential for bearing fruit.

Answer (score 1):

When we speak about animals or plants in the plural, we say *they,them,their*. We usually say *it,its* in the singular. Your pet is often regarded as *he* or *she*. When you read fairy-tales, you can also see *he* or *she* used to call animals.