# Can we use "him" for an animal in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, gender

Can we use "him" for an animal for the passive form? Please check my below sentence and kindly let me know if I used "him" at the end of the sentence.

> "When deer saw the lion running at him, he started to run faster and vanish in the jungle".

Comment: Related questions: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53132/ http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/52891/

Comment: What "passive form" are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sex of the animal is undetermined you should use the neutral pronoun, so you would use "it" in your example. You can use *he* or *she* for pets, but you should make the sex of the animal clear. Always use *he* or *she* if the animal has been given a name.

Having said that, your example presents a slight problem if we use "it" in both clauses:

> When the deer saw the lion running at it, it started to run faster and
>   vanished in the jungle.

It is not immediately clear what the second "it" refers to: the deer or the lion. We could resolve this by putting:

> The deer started to run faster when it saw the lion running at it, and
>   vanished into the jungle.

Note that, in your example, *deer* needs a definite article and the tenses of *start* and *vanish* should match.